# How to disable log that when compile?

Tags: hardhat, compiler

[image]
I using script "yarn hardhat compile" alway log like image. I want to disable that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure the hardhat conf file `hardhat.config.js` with the `quiet` property. Here is an example:

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");

module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.4", // Your Solidity version
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200,
      },
      quiet: true, // Add this line to disable the logging
    },
  },
  // Other configurations
};
```

Comment: I tried but couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: I found the reason, delete package "@tenderly/hardhat-tenderly" in hardhat.config.ts to solve. thank you.